# Add complete xml as a child of an xml node in python using xml

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have the following xmls (simplified):

Base:

```
<root>
    <child1></child1>
    <child2></child2>
</root>
```

ChildInfo:

```
<ChildInfo>
    <Name>Something</Name>
    <School>ElementarySchool</School>
    <Age>7</Age>
</ChildInfo>
```

ExpectedOutput:

```
<root>
    <child1></child1>
    <child2>
        <ChildInfo>
            <Name>Something</Name>
            <School>ElementarySchool</School>
            <Age>7</Age>
        </ChildInfo>
    </child2>
</root>
```

This case is simplified just to provide the functionality I need. The XMls in the real case scenario are really big so creating a subelement line by line is not an option, so parsing a xml file is the only way I can do it.

I have the following until now

pythonfile.py:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

finalScript=ET.parse(r"resources/JmeterBase.xml")
samplerChild=ET.parse(r"resources/JmeterSampler.xml")
root=finalScript.getroot()
samplerChildRoot=ET.Element(samplerChild.getroot())
root.append(samplerChildRoot)
```

But this is not giving the desired option and in all xml guides the samples are really simple and dont deal with this cases.

Is there a way to load a complete xml file and sabe it as an element that can be added as a whole? or should I just change libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load `JmeterSampler.xml` directly as Element when using `ET.fromstring(...)`, then you just need to append the Element to the place you want:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

finalScript = ET.parse(r"resources/JmeterBase.xml")
samplerChild = ET.fromstring(open(r"resources/JmeterSampler.xml").read())
root = finalScript.getroot()

child2 = root.find('child2')
child2.append(samplerChild)

print (ET.tostring(root, 'utf-8'))
```

Prints:

```
<root>
    <child1 />
    <child2><ChildInfo>
    <Name>Something</Name>
    <School>ElementarySchool</School>
    <Age>7</Age>
    </ChildInfo>
    </child2>
</root>
```